# Como selecionar um option com comparação de valores?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Eu preciso fazer `"selected='selected'"` num `option` cujo seu valor é o que está gravado na variável **estado** recuperada no Ajax. Como eu posso fazer isso?

```
$('#cep').on("change", function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://cep.republicavirtual.com.br/web_cep.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        data:{
            cep: $('#cep').val(),
            formato:'json'
        },
        success: function(res){

            res.uf; = "24";
            estado = res.uf;
...

// Estados dentro do select ... 

<select name="estado" id="estado" class="form-control mb-md">
    <option value="">Selecione um estado ...</option>
    <option value="1">Acre</option>
    <option value="2">Alagoas</option>
    <option value="3">Amazonas</option>
    <option value="4">Amapá</option>
    ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode fazer um each no seu seletor de options e verificar se o valor bate com o seu retorno, e depois disso adicionar selected a opção.

**Exemplo:**

```js
var valorEstado = 3;

$("#estado option").each(function() {
  if (this.value == valorEstado) {
    $(this).attr('selected', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="estado" id="estado">
  <option value="">Selecione um estado ...</option>
  <option value="1">Acre</option>
  <option value="2">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="3">Amazonas</option>
  <option value="4">Amapá</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4):

Eu costumo apenas alterar o valor (value) e o estado é selecionado automaticamente, ficaria assim:

```js
var estado = 3;
$("#estado").val(estado);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="estado" id="estado">
  <option value="">Selecione um estado</option>
  <option value="1">Acre</option>
  <option value="2">Alagoas</option>
  <option value="3">Amazonas</option>
  <option value="4">Amapá</option>
</select>
```

Comment: +1, Gostei bastante dessa resposta, faz muito sentido selecionar a option que o valor bate, acredito que para quem tem um bom entendimento do select seja tão legível quanto percorrer os elementos. se você for na verdade observar a implementação de val() do jQuery ele verifica se o seletor possui a propriedade value, e se não tiver procura pelos seus filhos, nisso ele reutiliza o each que eu utilizei na minha resposta. acaba que em questão de desempenho o seu faz uma verificação a mais, mas o desempenho nem pode ser levado em consideração, sendo que é pouca coisa.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues então, não sei se é a melhor maneira, mas é bem simples e funcional e como vc disse, neste caso o desempenho não é um fator crítico logo optar pela simplicidade faz sentido.

Answer (score 2):

O mais comum nesses casos é atribuir uma ID ou classe específica pra cada termo, que vc consiga referenciar diretamente na resposta, tipo `$('#uf'+estado)`. Se não for possível você pode selecionar a option correta usando

```
// primeiro retira qualquer seleção anterior
$('option').prop('selected', false);
// depois seleciona somente a option com o value correto
$('option[value='+estado+']').prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Depois de pegar o estado, faça assim:

```js
estado = 3;
$('#estado').find("option[value='"+estado+"']").attr('selected', 'selected');
```