# Retornando um Select option com Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá pessoal tudo bem todos, preciso humildemente da ajuda de vocês estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho um scrpt Ajax com os estados e cidades do brasil, 
e um select option onde lista o estado e o outro suas respectivas cidades, ate ai tudo bem, apos eu selecionar uma cidade e um estado, eu consigo gravar no banco normalmente, minha dificuldade é na hora de editar esse select ele fica em branco, não vem selecionado o que esta na tabela, ele volta vazio listando do Ajax os estados e cidades,

Eu não sei fazer, mas tem como ao chamar esse select para editar ele percorrer e comparar a  lista no Ajax com o que consta na coluna da tabela e já ficar  selecionado ?

HTML:

```
<select id="estados">
  <option value=""></option>
</select>

<select id="cidades" >
<option value=""></option>
</select>
```

JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.getJSON('estados_cidades.json', function (data) {

            var items = [];
            var options = '<option value="">escolha um estado</option>';    

            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                options += '<option value="' + val.nome + '">' + val.nome + '</option>';
            });                 
            $("#estados").html(options);                

            $("#estados").change(function () {              

                var options_cidades = '';
                var str = "";                   

                $("#estados option:selected").each(function () {
                    str += $(this).text();
                });

                $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                    if(val.nome == str) {                           
                        $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
                            options_cidades += '<option value="' + val_city + '">' + val_city + '</option>';
                        });                         
                    }
                });

                $("#cidades").html(options_cidades);

            }).change();        

        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo desse JSON em `data`? Vêm como array?

Comment: da uma olhada nessa pergunta, bem parecida: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/160102/como-selecionar-um-option-com-compara%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-valores/160105#160105

Comment: Semana passada trabalhei em um formulário com os 3 combos, cidade estado e pais, na pagina de edição, como já conheço os 3 itens selecionados, monto os combos já contendo todas suas devidas opções e dou um selected nos itens selecionados...

Comment: Ainda não consegui resolver, sou iniciante em programação, se alguém poder me ajudar eu agradeço muito.

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que você esteja tentando fazer algo parecido com isso.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('estados_cidades.json', function (data) {
        $("#estados").append('<option value="">Escolha um estado</option>');

        $.each(data, function (key, val) {
            $("#estados").append('<option></option>', {value: val.nome, text:val.nome});
        });
    });

    $("#estados").change(function () {
        $("#cidades").html('');
        $.getJSON('estados_cidades.json', function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (key, val) {
                if(val.nome == $(this).value()) {
                    $.each(val.cidades, function (key_city, val_city) {
                        $("#cidades").append($('<option></option>', {value: val_city, text: val_city}));
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```